# Not able to upload a .jpg image using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to upload a .jpg file in web page using `Choose file | Locator | File Path` command. But it just opens the Windows folder, not navigating to the File Path which I've given.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Home_Page_URL}    https://34.239.9.24:8443/LIVMOR/
${FilePath}       C:\\Users\\20073018\\Desktop\\Pranesh_Kulkarni.jpg

*** Test Cases ***
.
.
TC9-Change Profile Picture
    Click Element    xpath=//a[@onclick="openAttachment()"]
    Choose File      xpath=//a[@onclick="openAttachment()"]    ${FilePath}
```

Comment: The file name should be stored in an `<input ....>` element. From your example you're clicking /trying to input it in a hyperlink element (`<a ...>`) have you tried to input (without clicking on the link) the file path in the nearest `<input ...>` element?

Comment: Can you please elobarate little more on this.?

Comment: In order to help you better, can you post the relevant HTML code containing the `<a href=...>` If needed, please use gist for larger blocks of code.

Comment: HTML Code: Actually it is a button, tapping on it, it opens the Windows file-
<a href="#" class="ar btn btn-primary" onclick="openAttachment()">CHANGE PROFILE PICTURE</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* be clicking on an element that opens a file chooser. Instead, you call `choose file` on the input element that is used to pass the filename to the server. The whole point of `choose file` is to avoid the popup dialog, since selenium can't control the dialog.

Comment: Yes Bryan, I agree.. But i have senario like follows:
1. I have a Change Profile picture, clicking on that, it allows me to select a file from Local System.